# How to select corresponding items of a columns without making it index column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

[image]

How do I get the price of an item1 without making 'Items column' an index column?

I tried `df['Price (R)'][item1]` but it returns the price of item2, while I expect output to be 1

Comment: IIUC `df.loc[df['Items'].eq('Item1') , 'Price (R)']` that said can you post your data as text and your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loc` operators are required in front of the selection brackets []. When using `loc`, the part before the comma is the rows you want, and the part after the comma is the columns you want to select. Therefore, the code can be:

```
result = df.loc[df['Items']=="item1","Price(R)"]
```

The data type of created output is Pandas Series object.